# Apache Jena Elephas and Hadoop for distributed rdf stores

Tags: java, hadoop, jena

The java project i am involved in tries to create a distributed rdf store, which will store RDF documents and will query them with SPARQL.

After some research i have done, i found out that this can be fulfilled with the use of Apache Hadoop, Apache Jena and Apache Jena Elephas.

Is there a way to find more examples than the default example which i found at the apache jena elephas site, explaining a way to achieve a good map and reduce in map/reduce phase for rdf documents?
Also are there more examples i can study in order to adopt in a better way the Apache Jena Elephas functionality?